# Why do a coset is isomorphic to a certain set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I have encountered with the proof of the next lemma

suppose G is a finite abelian p-group, and let $C$ a cyclic subgroup of maximal order, then $G=C\oplus H$ for some subgroup $H$

at http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf, but in the proof the say that

$(C+K)/K \cong C$

but the reason they give is only the following:

Because K has prime order, K∩C={e}, which implies that 
$(C+K)/K \cong C$ , but Can you proof in detail that implication please, is because I don't see why that is true, thank you a lot. I'll appreciate your answers.

**Is there an alternative proof of the one offer by @Hayden, thanks**

Answer (score 1):

The Second* Isomorphism Theorem (for Groups) states that for a group $G$, $S$ a subgroup of $G$, and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$, then

1. $SN=\{sn \in G \mid s\in S, n\in N\}$ is a subgroup of $G$,
2. $S\cap N$ is a normal subgroup of $S$, and
3. $(SN)/N\cong S/(S\cap N)$.

Thus, taking $G$ to be abelian (so we will use additive notation rather than multiplicative notation), we see that $$\frac{C+K}{K}\cong \frac{C}{C\cap K}=\frac{C}{\{e\}}\cong C.$$

(*: The ordering of the isomorphism theorems are not altogether standard, so this might be different than the numbering you might have seen before.  I'm using the numbering from wikipedia for simplicity.)

Comment: Ok an the second isomorphism is because the second isomorphism thm isn't :) ?

Comment: And which will be the normal subgroup N in our case ?

Comment: In the string of isomorphisms and equalities?  No, the first is due to the second isomorphism theorem, while the second is a simple group theoretic fact.

Comment: In this case $N$ is $K$.  There is no need to worry about normality of the subgroup in this case though because we are dealing with abelian groups.

Comment: Yes :) the first one I'm sorry :)

Comment: Which is that theoretical fact ?

Comment: And I have never seen this before :), can you give an alternative proof with other machinery less sofisticated please, just i case the teacher tell that we cant use this please :) thanks for the help :)

Comment: That $C/\{e\}\cong C$ follows from either noticing that the elements of $C/\{e\}$ are costs of the form $c\{e\}$ for $c\in C$, which is simply $\{c\}$, or using the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Is there anothr way to explain this with out that thms ?

Comment: What have you covered?  I would assume you are aware of quotient groups, what about the first isomorphism theorem (see wikipedia for reference)?  The other isomorphism theorems follow from this.

Comment: Oh yes I have seen wikipedia for reference, but in class we havent seen those thms I asking for an alternative proof just in case the teacher do not allow us to use this that is the only thing :), i think there will be no problem, jus in case ;)