# Question about a proof concerning abelian p-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, alternative-proof

[image: This is what I could find of this stuff in the books :)]
[image]
I want to prove (convincing myself), why is this rght. In the proof of the lemma

suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, and let $C$ a cyclic subgroup of maximal order, then $G=C\oplus H$ for some subgroup $H$

at http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf

they have that since $H\cap(C+K)= K$, we have $H\cap C=\{e\}$. But how do they have **the part of** $H\cap(C+K)= K$? is because they say that $H'$ is the preimage of a certain map, then they can do the following:

$G/K= (C+K)/K \oplus H/K$

**but I do not know if that is enough to justificate that step, or how can they have the conclusion that**  $H\cap(C+K)= K$**,and well the part that** $H\cap C=\{e\}$ **is obvious from here,** a**nd in the proof of the same lemma they say that because** $K$ **has prime order then** $K\cap C=\{e\}$,  **is that the only reason? Can someone prove those things please is because I don't see why is that true with the arguments presented in that proof. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: thanks for the edition can you help me with the question @KCd :)

Comment: Now you are repeating your question twice. Look over what you are writing and remove text that is duplicated.

Comment: Ok :) thanks for paying attention to my question :)

Comment: This result is in many books that discuss the cyclic decomposition of finite abelian groups. If you are not happy with the treatment in one source then look in others.

Comment: Can you post the link of one of them plaese :)

Comment: I meant physically go to the library and look at actual books. Have you looked at other approaches to the cyclic decomposition for finite abelian groups?

Comment: yes but only in the reference I posted :) I didnt try to do the thing you tell me because I do not know which book search :), a title recomended?

Comment: And another thing is the level, because of the undergraduate series that I need to look for :), that is why I was asking for help :)

Comment: Well I am actually at the library :)

Comment: I will post the images of the best that I could find :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $h\in H\cap C$. Note then that $h\in H\cap (C+K)=K$, so $h\in K$. But $K\cap C=\{e\}$.

Comment: Ok and we are done isnt :), Can you take a look to this for an alternative proof of the one offer by @Hayden please :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026625/why-do-a-coset-is-isomorphic-to-a-certain-set, thanks in advance :) for everything

Comment: Oooo the thing is how do they have the part of H∩(C+K)=K thanks :)